# Nintendo 64 Emulators

Tags: emulation

I've been constantly trying to get a nice Nintendo 64 Emulator in my Ubuntu 18.04 but I didn't find a good one as much as I look into it. I am not experienced with the Ubuntu interface overall so if anybody knows how to solve any of these problems, please try explaining exactly where should I go and what are the exact commands to solve them, if any.
So, I'm having the following problems with each of the emulators:

Mupen64plus - Can't configure controllers, I've been trying to find a tutorial that explains exactly how I should change the joystick buttons but everything seems overly complicated to me once I the only way of doing it is apparently changing a config file. I can't open a tab like any other emulator that configures each button while pressing it.

M64py - It just doesn't open.

Project 64 - Perfect, but I can't set it to full screen. Every time the game is on and I go Options > Full Screen , the window goes and comes back to what it was before. I also can't change anything in settings (for instance, to open at full screen straight away) because with Ubuntu I can't modify anything.

If someone knows how to fix any of these problems or have another Nintendo 64 Emulator, please, let me know how I can fix/download it with as much details as possible.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

just configure the left analog to do all the movements and the right for the c-pad and right trigger as your z-trigger and c-button can be one of your bumpers.

Comment: and not being able to go full-screen is something you can solve by looking up your o.s and the issue online.